# Convert polygon feature to line feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, polygon, line, geometry-conversion

I have a polygon shapefile I need to extract the line segments where the polygon features intersect each other and also the segment where they don't.

Can we automate this process or can scripting like ArcPy be used?

Comment: Just to clarify when you say "intersect" do you mean share a common boundary? 2 polygons intersecting may actually return an area as they are overlapping. It would be helpful if you upload a screen shot of your data. Is your data land usage so polygons share boundaries or is some sort of dataset representing overlapping regions, this needs to be known as it dictates what approach you would use.

Comment: you may be looking for this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70527/split-polygon-into-lines