# Split polygon into lines

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, geometry-conversion

I have a polygon layer which looks like this [image].

I used the QGIS `multiparts to singleparts` tool and also `polygon to lines`. In both cases i  got this type of result

[image].

I want to extract polygon into individual lines like this[image]

Comment: this looks like a similar question, which may answer the question - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48461/how-to-break-both-lines-at-their-points-of-intersection-in-qgis

Comment: I don't think the question is similar, and the answer is not useful as well. I use sextante in qgis.

Comment: not even if you convert the polys to lines first?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use line-to-polygon tool (See [How can I transform a polygon to a linestring in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15819/))
followed by v.clean command (See http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.clean.html).

Comment: Is there something for qgis

Comment: The first tools is from QGIS and is available through sextante analysis tools; Second comand is from GRASS, but is also available through Sextante (You need to have grass installed and configured in sextante).

Comment: take a look at : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32192/how-do-i-split-polygons-into-line-segments

Comment: first i used v.clean with break tool, then v.clean with rmdupl tool. The result are as i want but there are duplicates.